# Too much to test on the last day of the sprint

Tags: scrum, agile, sprint, testing

How can I avoid the issue where a lot of stories are moved to Under Testing on the last day of the sprint?

The Under Testing column is manageable on most days but on the last day and there day before the last day of the sprint we get an influx of cases getting finished and moved to the Under Testing. Many times we had to finish the sprint with  cases that haven't been tested.

We try to keep user stories as small as possible but it doesn't seem to eliminate this issue. Any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/30443/qas-get-all-the-work-at-the-end-of-sprint